# $q Promise in UI-Router Resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, deferred

Actually, this question can be simplified to "Return an $http or Restangular call result in a promise". My goal is to have a promise object that is resolved after an $http call completes:

```
var deferredCall= $q.defer();
```

Then this is resolved from the call:

```
$http.get (url)
   .then(function(result){ deferredCall.resolve('Success' + result);},
    function(){ deferredCall.resolve('Failure' + error););
```

Then I have a promise object that will be resolved when the call is complete (either succeeding or failing), this is what I want:

```
deferredCall.promise.then(function (value) {
    return //something to pass to controller;
});
```

The goal is that the controller is instantiated whether the resolve succeds or fails. My problem? Resolve can only take a promise, so: `deferredCall.promise. How do I resolve this promise with the call above withing the Resolve / through a service? Are the results of a service method a promise?

Like if I make a service whose method makes the $http call and then returns deferredCall?

Comment: why do u need $q for this?

Comment: I have no idea how else to do it while using angularjs. That's not me saying "There is no other way to do it" - I just really don't know how to approach this problem in javascript. $q was my guess. I am looking for whatever will achieve the end goal of having a promise that returns the results of an $http call whether it fails or succeeds. The call DOES need to be nested within another promise because if a resolve call fails, the controller isn't instantiated.

Comment: @VSO you don't need to Create another promise..just return the `$http.get` promise..

Comment: @VSO You don't use to $q both Restangular and $http will give you promise already...

Comment: @PankajParkar: That's what I am doing now, but it in some resolves it still fails if the controller throws an error. I am probably doing something else wrong. Will look at it now. Thanks.

Comment: @wickY26: I know, I need a promise within a promise, read the post on why if you feel like it.

Comment: Are you talking about resolve in $routeProvider, when instantiating controller and passing some preloaded data in it using resolve block ?

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin: Exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how we resolve data in our project:

Angular $routeProvider:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/something/something', {
        templateUrl: 'somewhere/some-details.html',
        controller : SomeController,
        resolve : {
            someItem : function (SomeService) {
                return SomeService.getSomethingAll();
            }
        }
    })
```

Controller:

```
var SomeController = function ($scope, someItem) {};
```

Data Service:

```
.service('SomeService', function (SomeUtils, $http) {
    return {
        getSomethingAll : function () {
            return SomeUtils.promiseHttpResult($http.get("api/something/all"));
        }
    }
})
```

Utils Service:

```
.service("SomeUtils", function($q) {
    return {
        promiseHttpResult: function (httpPromise) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            httpPromise.success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function () {
                deferred.reject(arguments);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Nice and simple. No skills required :) (DD)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.

Comment: Are you sure the last example works? In my case, deferred.promise is just accepted immediatly without waiting. Even if I comment resolve & reject out, it wents through